# Why is my function not printing anything in the CLI?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, pymongo

At the moment I am just trying to get the function to print what it has found in
the database, however I am not getting anything in the CLI when submitting
eywords via a form which has this functions URL as an action.

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MONGO_DBNAME"] = 'recipe_site'
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = os.getenv("MONGO_URI")

mongo = PyMongo(app)

#function for search bar.

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    mongo.db.recipes.create_index( { "name": "text" } )
    if request.method == "POST":
        q = request.form['search']
    else:
        q = ""
    query = ( { "$text": { "$search": q } } )
    results = mongo.db.recipes.find(query)
    
    return render_template('searchresults.html', recipes = results)
```

The form that calls search function and captures key search word:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('search', text=text) }}" method="POST">
    <div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="validate">
            <span class="helper-text" data-error="Try again" data-success="Done"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit </button>
</form>
```

## Error code

- Debugger PIN: 272-267-243
  10.240.1.220 - - [25/May/2019 19:24:14] "POST /search/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -

As the code stands now all I expect is that it should print any collections in my database which have the keyword searched using the form.

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: No error other than a 404 error for the webpage I am trying to redirect to but that is to be expected due to the print statement not working i don't currently know what the function is pulling from my database. I added a return on the end '    return redirect(url_for('searchresults.html'))'. Also here is my form action incase that helps diagnose. <form action="{{ url_for('search', text=text) }}" method="POST">

Comment: can you post your whole code ?

Comment: which mongo client are you using?

Comment: Erm theres a lot as its a whole recipe website project i am doing for a course. At the moment the only issue i am having is trying to implement a search bar using pymongo to search the database. In the original question is the full app route i am trying to write and i will post the full form below where i am trying to capture the key search words.

Comment: Mongodb atlast .

Comment: <form action="{{ url_for('search', text=text) }}" method="POST">
    <div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="validate">
            <span class="helper-text" data-error="Try again" data-success="Done"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit </button>
</form>

Comment: please post all the data by editing your question

Comment: I have edited the main question now

Comment: you should post the error log as well

Answer (score 0):

Using the official documentation for [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html)
Here is a tested code that might help.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import pymongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MONGO_DBNAME"] = 'test'
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-vhd1j.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"

mongo = PyMongo(app)

# mongo.db.collection.create_index([("name", pymongo.ASCENDING),("text", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
mongo.db.collection.insert_one({"name":"myname","text":"abcd"})
query = { "text": "abcd"}
results = mongo.db.collection.find(query)
for result in results:
  print(result)
```

you can manipulate it as per your requirement. :)
I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried changing it to this but it didnt not change the result at all, exactly same errors etc. According to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/ i should use $text and $search

Comment: You should refer to this https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Oh i see. But I did try and change the syntax to what you suggested but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the key words received from the post request using request.form['search']
like below:

```
#function for search bar.

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
   # index for field name
   mongo.db.recipes.create_index('name')

   # index for field name and example
   #mongo.db.recipes.create_index([("name", pymongo.DESCENDING),
   #("example", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
   if request.method == "POST":
     q=request.form['search']
   else:
     q = ""
   query = ( { "$text": { "$search": q } } )
   results = mongo.db.recipes.find(query)
   print (results)
   return render_template('searchresults.html', recipes = results)
```

In the form, you need to replace

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search', text=text) }}" method="POST">
```

By

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="POST">
```

Edit:
I suggest to use GET method instead of POST for search feature because when the client refresh the browser, it ask him to confirm Form submission. So we need to replace:

```
if request.method == "POST":
     q=request.form['search']
else:
     q = ""
```

By

```
q = request.args.get('search', "")
```

And

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="POST">
```

by

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="GET">
```

Comment: New error seems similar. TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'ensureIndex' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

Comment: sorry man. this should works mongo.db.recipes.ensure_index( { "name": "text" } )

Comment: pyMongo use create_index and ensure_index instead of createIndex and ensureIndex.

Comment: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index

Comment: Ah i see thanks. Looks like I am getting closer. The latest error message is 'TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list'. Any idea on this one?

Comment: you need to use return render_template(searchresults.html, 'results': results)

Comment: So i updated the return statement to include the captured key word as well (also updated my original question with latest code above) but i am still getting 'TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list' as an error.

Comment: Yeah. return render_template('searchresults.html', recipes = results)

Comment: No its the same error 'TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list'. I updated my original question with the most up to date code I have now.

Comment: use mongo.db.recipes.create_index('name'). If you want to create index for more than one field, you need to add direction ascendant or descendant.

Comment: Please see doc: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your attempts to support but I have now rectified the issue. The reason why nothing was printing in the cli was due the there being an issue with the create_index line. There was an existing index within that collection i was unaware of which was preventing this line from running.